# GWT SuperDevMode - mvn gwt:run-codeserver dosen't find translations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm trying to use the GWT SuperDevMode, so far I've got it running with a simple test project, but I get errors if I try to run the `mvn gwt:run-codeserver`:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.project.shared.client.translation.CommonTranslation
```

So here is the question: How do I add the gwt generated `CommonTranslation.java` to my plugin? (full path to the .java file: `target/generated-sources/gwt/com.project.shared.client.translation.CommonTranslation.java` )

The `gwt-maven-plugin` looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                <goal>i18n</goal>
                <!-- <goal>test</goal> -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <style>DETAILED</style>
        <runTarget>com.project.dashboard.Dashboard/index.html</runTarget>
        <runTarget>com.project.floorplan.Floorplan/floorplan.html</runTarget>
        <i18nMessagesBundles>
            <i18nConstantsBundle>com.project.shared.client.translation.CommonTranslation</i18nConstantsBundle>
            <i18nConstantsBundle>com.project.shared.client.translation.ValidationTranslation</i18nConstantsBundle>
        </i18nMessagesBundles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Full log output:

```
$: mvn gwt:run-codeserver

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.project.dashboard:dashboard:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for com.project.custom:custom-gwt-sdk:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 100, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for com.project.custom:custom-gwt-sdk:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 101, column 18
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.groupId' for com.project.custom:custom-java-sdk:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 113, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for com.project.custom:custom-java-sdk:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 114, column 18
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dashboard 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ dashboard >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:generateAsync (default) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:i18n (default) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Source directory: /home/user/mercurial/dashboard/target/generated-sources/gwt added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/user/mercurial/dashboard/war/WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ dashboard <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [com.project.floorplan.Floorplan, com.project.dashboard.Dashboard, com.project.fileservice.FileService, com.project.shared.Shared]
[INFO] workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-5202686560764367228.tmp
[INFO] DEBUG log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log) via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] binding: user.agent=safari
[INFO] binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
[INFO] binding: locale=en
[INFO] Compiling module com.project.floorplan.Floorplan
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 3 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:110)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptImmutable(JModVisitor.java:313)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.visitChildren(JMethodCall.java:251)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:242)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:117)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement.traverse(JExpressionStatement.java:41)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:138)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:134)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:449)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JConstructor.traverse(JConstructor.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:940)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:665)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:672)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:34)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:271)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:223)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:139)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:167)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:115)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.project.shared.client.translation.CommonTranslation
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.searchForTypeByBinary(UnifyAst.java:1009)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.translate(UnifyAst.java:1074)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.translate(UnifyAst.java:1126)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.access$900(UnifyAst.java:124)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.visit(UnifyAst.java:365)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:241)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptImmutable(JModVisitor.java:305)
[INFO]  ... 37 more
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(21): CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText()
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(21): this.termsAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText())
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(21): this.termsAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText())
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(15): {
[INFO]   super();
[INFO]   this.$init();
[INFO]   FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
[INFO]   panel.setStyleName("col-12 footer");
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor = new Anchor();
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText());
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor.setText(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText());
[INFO]   panel.add(this.termsAnchor);
[INFO]   panel.add(this.termsAnchor);
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor = new Anchor();
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.imprintText());
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor.setText(CommonHelper.cTranslation.imprintText());
[INFO]   panel.add(this.imprintAnchor);
[INFO]   this.initWidget(panel);
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(15): {
[INFO]   super();
[INFO]   this.$init();
[INFO]   FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
[INFO]   panel.setStyleName("col-12 footer");
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor = new Anchor();
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText());
[INFO]   this.termsAnchor.setText(CommonHelper.cTranslation.termsText());
[INFO]   panel.add(this.termsAnchor);
[INFO]   panel.add(this.termsAnchor);
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor = new Anchor();
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor.setTitle(CommonHelper.cTranslation.imprintText());
[INFO]   this.imprintAnchor.setText(CommonHelper.cTranslation.imprintText());
[INFO]   panel.add(this.imprintAnchor);
[INFO]   this.initWidget(panel);
[INFO] }
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
[INFO]       [ERROR] at FooterView.java(15): public FooterView();
[INFO] 
[INFO]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JConstructor
[INFO] [ERROR] Compiler returned false
[ERROR] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:128)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.864s
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:run-codeserver (default-cli) on project dashboard: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/user/mercurial/dashboard/war/WEB-INF/classes:/home/user/mercurial/dashboard/src/main/java:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/github/branflake2267/gwt-maps-api/3.9.0-build-17/gwt-maps-api-3.9.0-build-17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader/1.1.0/gwt-ajaxloader-1.1.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/google-apis/gwt-visualization/1.0.2/gwt-visualization-1.0.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/project/custom/custom-gwt-sdk/0.1.1/custom-gwt-sdk-0.1.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/project/custom/custom-java-sdk/0.1.1/custom-java-sdk-0.1.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend/backend-core/2.0.30/backend-core-2.0.30-tests.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.2/mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-mongodb/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.7.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend/backend-model/2.0.30/backend-model-2.0.30.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-lgpl/1.9.0/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend-admin/backend-admin-model/2.0.30/backend-admin-model-2.0.30.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend/backend-persistence/2.0.30/backend-persistence-2.0.30.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/jparsec/jparsec/2.0.1/jparsec-2.0.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.1_3/cglib-2.1_3.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/easymock/easymock/2.0/easymock-2.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend/backend-commons/2.0.30/backend-commons-2.0.30.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/backend/backend-refclient/2.0.30/backend-refclient-2.0.30.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/2.6/hazelcast-2.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast-client/2.6/hazelcast-client-2.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.5/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.2/httpclient-4.3.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.1/httpcore-4.3.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.2/jettison-1.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-bundle/1.17/jersey-bundle-1.17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.17/jersey-json-1.17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17/jersey-core-1.17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.17/jersey-server-1.17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/rosaloves/bitlyj/2.0.0/bitlyj-2.0.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/notnoop/apns/apns/0.1.6/apns-0.1.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.0/jackson-core-asl-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.0/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.0/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.0/jackson-xc-1.9.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xmlrpc/0.7/groovy-xmlrpc-0.7.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.0/groovy-all-1.7.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/jivesoftware/smack/3.0.4/smack-3.0.4.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/media/jai_imageio/1.1/jai_imageio-1.1.pom:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/media/jai-codec/1.1.3/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/code/javaparser/javaparser/1.0.1/javaparser-1.0.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.9-RC1/reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA/javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/sun/codemodel/codemodel/2.6/codemodel-2.6.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.2/joda-time-2.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.5/tika-core-1.5.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-codeserver/2.6.0/gwt-codeserver-2.6.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer -sourceLevel 1.7 com.project.floorplan.Floorplan com.project.dashboard.Dashboard com.project.fileservice.FileService com.project.shared.Shared
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** `mvn process-classes gwt:run-codeserver`

[Seemingly there is a bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/0FOyhQNfD-k) with `gwt:run-codeserver`, so if you do not run `process-classes` before running the CodeServer, the translation files located in:

```
target/generated-sources/gwt/com.project.shared.client.translation.CommonTranslation.java
```

will not be discovered and maven fails with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.